# Looking for a pragmatic XML-Document Builder Design

Tags: xml, templates

We have to create numerous XML-Documents, satisfying a huge XML-Schema. The documents vary in size and structure. The most basic documents only contain about 10 elements but there are also complex documents with hundreds of elements, repetition, optional branches, etc.
We are looking for a way to design some lightweight abstraction to help building those documents and filling it with the data from business models.
The abstraction does not need to validate the resulting document and does not need to assert invariants.

Is there any basic technology, like XSLT, that helps us creating those documents?
I am not able to spend a lot of time to build a full fleged OO-abstraction/Builder, so I am looking for a very pragmatic, least effort solution to aid in constructing these documents.

General ideas are most welcomed. Our environment supports full OOP but no FP :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be lightweight markup/template engine like [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml) or [Haml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haml) may be useful for this purposes? There are lots of implementations in many programming languages for them and many text editors support highlightning for their syntax.